# Prevent set focus onClick if the input already has focus in ReactJS

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

ReactJS/Material-UI newbie question. I have a functional component which makes of useEffect and hooks. For simplicity, I created the code example below. If you click anywhere within the boundary of the autocomplete container (denoted by red border) it will set focus on the input field. But if you click in the boundary again you will notice it will set focus again. I'm trying to only set focus on the input field if focus on the input field isn't already set without resorting to using document.activeElement and avoiding anti-patterns. I'm current using useRef but not sure if I need to make use of useEffect, useState, or if I can somehow just leverage the autocomplete component by checking to see if the option list if visible or not. Any assistance is greatly appreciated. Link to sandbox https://codesandbox.io/s/solitary-fog-2t7p4?file=/src/demo.js

Code example

```
import React from "react";
import TextField from "@material-ui/core/TextField";
import Autocomplete from "@material-ui/lab/Autocomplete";

export default function ComboBox() {
  const container = React.useRef();
  const input = React.useRef();

  return (
    <>
      <div
        ref={container}
        style={{ padding: 30, border: "1px solid red" }}
        onClick={() => {
          if (!input.current.focused) {
            input.current.focus();
          }
        }}
      >
        <Autocomplete
          options={top100Films}
          getOptionLabel={(option) => option.title}
          openOnFocus
          selectOnFocus
          style={{ width: 300 }}
          renderInput={(params) => (
            <TextField
              inputRef={input}
              {...params}
              label="Combo box"
              variant="outlined"
            />
          )}
        />
      </div>
    </>
  );
}

// Top 100 films as rated by IMDb users. http://www.imdb.com/chart/top
const top100Films = [
  { title: "The Shawshank Redemption", year: 1994 },
  { title: "The Godfather", year: 1972 },
  { title: "The Godfather: Part II", year: 1974 },
  { title: "The Dark Knight", year: 2008 },
  { title: "12 Angry Men", year: 1957 }];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use the `mousedown` event instead

```js
onMouseDown={(event) => {
  event.preventDefault();
  input.current.focus();
}}
```

Not sure how to handle this on mobile, try the `touchstart` event.

Comment: Thanks a bunch! That did the trick. Simple solution. I was overthinking this as I wasn't sure if it needed useState or useEffect. I haven't decided on whether I will keep this functionality on mobile or not so not concerned with it working or not working on mobile at this point. Thanks again!